# Transform XSLT replacing inner <div> html

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XML and XSLT and I have been copy/pasting code I found to suit some of my situations.
I think I got the code mostly right but there's one thing I can't get around.
Expected output - depending on which button is pushed, it will load one of two transformed XLM 'pages' in a div called 'example'.

This is what's in the script and it works 'as is'.
document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);

Now I don't want to append the child, I just want to replace what's there because if they click the buttons more than once I get tables on tables.

I've tried variations on this:
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=resultDocument;

I also tried an if then statement checking to see if the div was blank or not and still no dice.

I can post more of my code, but I'm pretty sure this is what's fudging it up.

BTW - it works 'as is' in FireFox but not IE (question for another group I know) which I need it to because my audience will be using IE9+ only.

Comment: Can you update your question with a small example of the code you are using? Right now your question is tagged XML and XSLT but I don't see either here. Plus this sounds like more of a Javascript problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to show us your code that creates and assigns `resultDocument`. Normally within IE the XSLT API is the one of MSXML and the result of e.g. `transformNode` is a string and not a document or a DOM node. So I am astonished that within IE you have `document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);` working. But if you have it then doing

```
var element = document.getElementById("example");
element.innerText = ''; // removes any content
element.appendChild(resultDocument);
```

should suffice to replace the contents of the element with the nodes in the variable `resultDocument`.